# How to check if ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> contains a certain ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arraylist, equals

The title sheds good light on the trouble I am having, here is my code:

```
// fields required for traversal
private Queue<ArrayList<String>> q;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> r;

Set<String> stringList = getMeStrings();
for(String s : stringList)
{
    ArrayList<String> stringsRoute = new ArrayList<String>();
    stringsRoute.add(getSomeString());
    stringsRoute.add(s);
    if(!r.contains(stringList))
    {
        if(!q.contains(stringList))
        {
            q.add(stringList);                          
        }
        r.add(stringList);
    }
}
```

My If statement inside the For loop always fails, and I think the reason is because I am creating a new ArrayList object (different reference) and my If statement isn't checking to see if the contents of each of the ArrayLists in [ r ] contain the same elements in same order .. etc

I know one needs to use .equals in order to find out if two ArrayLists are similiar, but I have an ArrayList that houses many other ArrayLists.

How can I check if the parent ArrayList contains an ArrayList that equates to the new ArrayList I am creating?

I hope it is clear what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks

Comment: Please do not start variable names with a capital... `StringsRoute` looks like a class instead of a variable!

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that `stringsRoute` will always contain 2 elements?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out jlordo, I will need to change that later, but for now I am just after a neat solution for the main problem. thanks again.

Comment: @Ciwan: Well, the way it is now (always 2 Strings) I would introduce a class `StringTuple` and provide an `equals` method for that and use a `List<StringTuple>` instead of `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: @Ciwan...Are you aware that you are going inside the if loop if your arraylist r does not contain arrayList stringList?Your if loop will always fail if stringList arraylist is present in the main arraylist r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to traverse the whole `ArrayList` and then compare each element of the `ArrayList` with `StringsRoute` using `equals` method of ArrayList class.
To implement the foreach loop you could consider getting the size of `ArrayList`. If we have `ArrayList ar=new ArrayList();` we can user `ar.size()` to return the size and then simply run a for loop `ar.size()` times to iterate each element in the corressponding `ArrayList`.
Hopefully that solves your problem.

Comment: So a foreach loop? I am terrible at those. :( I know how to say it by words, but not code it ! >> foreach ArrayList<string> in r, see if it equals to given ArrayList. If any of them equate, set some bool to true?

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

For "StringsRoute" to be contained in "r" , there must be a list in "r" with the same elements in the same order.

```
Arrays.asList("1","2") .equals(Arrays.asList("2","1")) == false

Arrays.asList("1","2") .equals(Arrays.asList("1","2")) == true

Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("1","2")).contains(Arrays.asList("1","2")) == true

Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("1","2")).contains(Arrays.asList("2","1")) == false
```

May be you want to use a list of sets to avoid struggling with order.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

```
List< Set< String > > r;
```

Since:

```
new HashSet(Arrays.asList("1","2")).equals(new HashSet(Arrays.asList("2","1"))) == true
```